# How to convert a JSON structure into an array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, charts, angular6

I have a json response like follow,

```
[  
 {  
   "Value":"80,120"
 },
 {  
   "value2":"117,120"
 },
 {  
   "value3":"105,111"
 },
 {  
   "value4":"40,77"
 },
 {  
   "value5":"27,44"
 }
]
```

How to form this json structure in to a table to dynamically draw a barchart? Right now I'am statically mentioning the values here.

```
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['value', '80', '120'],
    ['value1', '70', '300'],
    ['value2', '90', '400'],
    ['value3', '100', '230']
  ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're planning to draw a google chart with that data,
you'll need to convert the values from strings to numbers.

from...

```
['value', '80', '120'],
```

to...

```
['value', 80, 120],
```

otherwise, you will receive the following error...

`Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string`

---

you can use the `map` method, as suggested in the other answers,
use `parseFloat` or `parseInt` to convert the strings to numbers.

the following will work...

```js
    var dataObj = [
      {
        "Value":"80,120"
      },
      {
        "value2":"117,120"
      },
      {
        "value3":"105,111"
      },
      {
        "value4":"40,77"
      },
      {
        "value5":"27,44"
      }
    ];

    var dataArray = dataObj.map(function (row) {
      var keys = Object.keys(row);
      var values = row[keys[0]].split(',');
      return [keys[0], parseFloat(values[0]), parseFloat(values[1])];
    });

    console.log(JSON.stringify(dataArray));
```

---

also, since the array data does not include column headings,
you will need to use `true` for the "first row is data" argument in `arrayToDataTable`,
which is the second argument...

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray, true);
```

following is a working example using a google chart...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var dataObj = [
    {
      "Value":"80,120"
    },
    {
      "value2":"117,120"
    },
    {
      "value3":"105,111"
    },
    {
      "value4":"40,77"
    },
    {
      "value5":"27,44"
    }
  ];

  var dataArray = dataObj.map(function (row) {
    var keys = Object.keys(row);
    var values = row[keys[0]].split(',');
    return [keys[0], parseFloat(values[0]), parseFloat(values[1])];
  });

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray, true);

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed explanation & code. You are lifesaver! Thanks a lot. @WhiteHat

Answer (score 1):

The one-liner below will do it, using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
const data = json.map(e => ([[k, v]] = Object.entries(e), [k, ...v.split(',')]));
```

Here's a complete snippet:

```js
const json = [{
    "value": "80,120"
  },
  {
    "value2": "117,120"
  },
  {
    "value3": "105,111"
  },
  {
    "value4": "40,77"
  },
  {
    "value5": "27,44"
  }];
  
const data = json.map(e => ([[k, v]] = Object.entries(e), [k, ...v.split(',')]));

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), like this:

```
const data = json.map(function(a) {
  return [...Object.keys(a), ...Object.values(a)[0].split(",")];
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
const json = [{
    "value": "80,120"
  },
  {
    "value2": "117,120"
  },
  {
    "value3": "105,111"
  },
  {
    "value4": "40,77"
  },
  {
    "value5": "27,44"
  }
];

const data = json.map(function(a) {
  return [...Object.keys(a), ...Object.values(a)[0].split(",")]
});

console.log(data);
```